# Clang AST how to match unary operator calls, excluding ones in decltype?

Tags: clang, llvm

I can easily match unary operator calls with the following query:

```
m unaryOperator(unless(isExpansionInSystemHeader()))
```

However, I want to exclude matches like the following:

```
decltype(&Func)
```

Is there a query that I can use to exclude those calls, or I should somehow exclude them from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [Traversal Matchers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html#traversal-matchers). For example,

```
// test.cpp
int foo();

int main() {
  int i=0;
  i++;

  int *k = &i;

  decltype(&foo) j;
  return 0;
}
```

with `clang-query test.cpp --`.

To match all unary operators:

```
clang-query> m unaryOperator()

Match #1:

/.../test.cpp:6:3: note: "root" binds here
  i++;
  ^~~

Match #2:

/.../test.cpp:8:12: note: "root" binds here
  int *k = &i;
           ^~

Match #3:

/.../test.cpp:10:12: note: "root" binds here
  decltype(&foo) j;
           ^~~~
3 matches.
```

To exclude `&`:

```
clang-query> m unaryOperator(unless(hasOperatorName("&")))

Match #1:

/.../test.cpp:6:3: note: "root" binds here
  i++;
  ^~~
1 match.
```

To exclude `decltype`:

```
clang-query> m unaryOperator(unless(hasAncestor(varDecl(hasType(decltypeType())))))

Match #1:

/.../test.cpp:6:3: note: "root" binds here
  i++;
  ^~~

Match #2:

/.../test.cpp:8:12: note: "root" binds here
  int *k = &i;
           ^~
2 matches.
```